# How can I fix a macro not being defined when I link a source file?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

### Problem

I have a header file called "SythConsole.h", where I defined a preprocessor conditional statement.

```
#ifndef UNICODE
    #error Please enable unicode for compiler!
#endif
```

I have defined the `UNICODE` macro within my main file, however when I link the source file( "SythConsole.cpp") and compile. I get an error telling me that `UNICODE` has not been defined in my main file. How can I link the source file object with the main file object?

Error:

> #error Please enable unicode for compiler!

Another Error that occurred (too few arguments):

> C:\Programming\C++\Libraries\windowEngine\main.cpp:45:48: error: no matching function for call to 'Syth::consoleWindow::ConstructConsole(int, int, int, int, const wchar_t [5])'
> window.ConstructConsole(100,100,8,8,L"Test");

> C:\Programming\C++\Libraries\windowEngine\include/SythConsole.h:51:17: note: candidate: 'int Syth::consoleWindow::ConstructConsole(int, int, int, int, std::__cxx11::wstring, bool)'
> int ConstructConsole(int width, int height, int fontW, int fontH, std::wstring t_winName, bool t_CursorVis);

I don't know why this error is occurring because there is a default argument for `t_CursorVis`.

### What I have tried

I have tried not link the source file and compile everything from the main file, where I put `#include SythConsole.cpp` in the bottom of the header file. The result from this change, allowed me to compile and no errors were thrown.

### Information and Source Code

My compile command:

`g++ main.cpp src/SythConsole.cpp -o main.exe`

My workspace:

- include

  - SythConsole.h
- src

  - SythConsole.cpp
- main.cpp

main.cpp source code:

```
#define UNICODE
#include "include/SythConsole.h"

int main()
{
    Syth::consoleWindow window;
    window.ConstructConsole(100,100,8,8,L"Test");
    while (true)
    {
        /* code */
    }
    
}
```

SythConsole.cpp:

```
#include "../include/SythConsole.h"

//Protected
namespace Syth
{

    int consoleWindow::MakeError(const wchar_t *msg)
    {
        wchar_t buffer[256];  // Buffer for containing the error message 
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buffer, 256, NULL); // Format the Error message from GetLastError()
        SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(m_hConsoleOrgi);  // Set the screen buffer to the intial screen buffer so the error can be displayed without any interference from the current buffer
        std::wcout << "Error: " << msg << " " << buffer << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }


    // Public
    consoleWindow::consoleWindow() : m_ScreenWidth(80), m_ScreenHeight(30), m_MouseX(0), m_MouseY(0), m_WinName(L"Console"), m_CursorVis(false)
    {
        m_hConsoleOrgi = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        m_hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
        m_hConsoleIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    }

    int consoleWindow::ConstructConsole(int width, int height, int fontW, int fontH, std::wstring t_winName = L"Console", bool t_CursorVis = false)
    {
        if (m_hConsole == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            return MakeError(L"INVALID HANDLE");

        m_ScreenWidth = width;
        m_ScreenHeight = height;
        m_WinName = t_winName;
        m_RectWindow = {0, 0, 1, 1};
        SetConsoleWindowInfo(m_hConsole, TRUE, &m_RectWindow);

        COORD xyCoord { (short)m_ScreenWidth, (short)m_ScreenHeight };

        if (!SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(m_hConsole, xyCoord))
            return MakeError(L"SetConsoleScreenBufferSize");
        
        if (!SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(m_hConsole))
            return MakeError(L"SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer");
        
        CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
        cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
        cfi.nFont = 0;
        cfi.dwFontSize.X = fontW;
        cfi.dwFontSize.Y = fontH;
        cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
        cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
        wcscpy_s(cfi.FaceName, L"Terminal");

        if (!SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(m_hConsole, false,&cfi))
            return MakeError(L"SetCurrentConsoleFontEx");
        
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
        // Check if the size given by the programmer is bigger than the screen buffer
        if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(m_hConsole,&csbi))
            return MakeError(L"GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo");
        
        if (m_ScreenHeight > csbi.dwMaximumWindowSize.Y)
            return MakeError(L"Screen Height is too big");

        if (m_ScreenWidth > csbi.dwMaximumWindowSize.X)
            return MakeError(L"Screen Width is too big");

        short tempWidth = m_ScreenWidth-1;
        short tempHeight = m_ScreenHeight-1;
        m_RectWindow = {0, 0, tempWidth, tempHeight};
        
        // Changes the dimensions of the Window 
        if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(m_hConsole, TRUE, &m_RectWindow))
            return MakeError(L"SetConsoleWindowInfo");
        
        if (!SetConsoleMode(m_hConsoleIn, ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS))
            return MakeError(L"SetConsoleMode");
        
        wchar_t title[256];
        swprintf(title,256,m_WinName.c_str());
        SetConsoleTitle(title);

        CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
        if (!GetConsoleCursorInfo(m_hConsole, &cci))
            return MakeError(L"GetConsoleCursorInfo");
        
        cci.bVisible = t_CursorVis;
        m_CursorVis = t_CursorVis;

        if (!SetConsoleCursorInfo(m_hConsole,&cci))
            return MakeError(L"SetCnsoleCursorInfo");
        
        // Create the screen buffer that stores data to be displayed on screen 
        m_ScreenBuf = new CHAR_INFO[m_ScreenWidth*m_ScreenHeight];
        memset(m_ScreenBuf, 0, sizeof(CHAR_INFO)*m_ScreenHeight*m_ScreenWidth);  // Sets all the unintialized 

        return 1;
    }

    int consoleWindow::getWidth() const { return m_ScreenWidth; }
    int consoleWindow::getHeight() const { return m_ScreenHeight; }
    int consoleWindow::getMouseX() const { return m_MouseX; }
    int consoleWindow::getMouseY() const { return m_MouseY; }
    
    void consoleWindow::handleMouseEvent(INPUT_RECORD &t_Record)
    {
        switch (t_Record.Event.MouseEvent.dwEventFlags)
        {
            case MOUSE_MOVED:
                m_MouseX = t_Record.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X;
                m_MouseY = t_Record.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    void consoleWindow::updateInputEvents()
    {
        DWORD numEvents {0};
        GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(m_hConsoleIn, &numEvents);

        if (numEvents == 0)
            return;

        INPUT_RECORD recordBuf[128];
        ReadConsoleInput(m_hConsoleIn,recordBuf, numEvents, &numEvents);

        for (DWORD i {0}; i < numEvents; i++)
        {
            switch (recordBuf[i].EventType)
            {
                case MOUSE_EVENT:
                    handleMouseEvent(recordBuf[i]);
                    break;
                
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    void consoleWindow::clip(int &t_X, int &t_Y)
    {
        if (t_X < 0) t_X = 0;
        if (t_X >= m_ScreenWidth) t_X = m_ScreenWidth;
        
        if (t_Y < 0) t_Y = 0;
        if (t_Y >= m_ScreenHeight) t_Y = m_ScreenHeight;

    }

    void consoleWindow::draw(int t_X, int t_Y, short t_Char, short t_Attribute)
    {
        if (t_X >= 0 && t_X <= m_ScreenWidth && t_Y >= 0 && t_Y <= m_ScreenHeight)
        {
            m_ScreenBuf[m_ScreenWidth * t_Y + t_X].Char.UnicodeChar = t_Char;
            m_ScreenBuf[m_ScreenWidth * t_Y + t_X].Attributes = t_Attribute;
        }
    }

    void consoleWindow::fill(Syth::coord t_Start, Syth::coord t_End, short t_Char, short t_Attribute)
    {
        for (int i {t_Start.x}; i <= t_End.x; i++)
        {
            for (int z {t_Start.y}; z <= t_End.y; z++)
            {
                draw(i,z,t_Char,t_Attribute);
            }
        }
    }

    void consoleWindow::drawString(int t_X, int t_Y, std::wstring t_String, short t_Attribute)
    {
        for (int i {0}, width {t_X}; i < t_String.size(); i++, width++)
        {
            draw(width,t_Y,t_String.at(i), t_Attribute);
        }
    }

    void consoleWindow::drawTriangle(coord vertex1, coord vertex2, coord vertex3, short t_Char, short t_Attribute)
    {
        drawLine(vertex1, vertex2 ,t_Char, t_Attribute);
        drawLine(vertex2, vertex3, t_Char, t_Attribute);
        drawLine(vertex3, vertex1, t_Char, t_Attribute);
    }

     void consoleWindow::drawLine(coord t_p1, coord t_p2, short t_Char, short t_Attribute)
    {
        float slope = 0.0f;

        if (t_p1.x != t_p2.x)
            slope = ((float)t_p2.y - (float)t_p1.y) / ((float)t_p2.x - (float)t_p1.x);
        

        if (t_p1.x != t_p2.x && abs(slope) <= 1.0f)
        {

            if (t_p1.x > t_p2.x)
                std::swap(t_p1, t_p2);

            float c {t_p1.y - slope*t_p1.x};

            for (int i {t_p1.x}; i < t_p2.x; i++)
            {
                int bufferY = slope * i + c;
                draw(i,bufferY, t_Char, t_Attribute);
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            if (t_p1.y > t_p2.y)
                std::swap(t_p1, t_p2);
            
            float slopeY { ((float)t_p1.x - (float)t_p2.x) / ((float)t_p1.y - (float)t_p2.y)};
            float cY {t_p1.x - slopeY*t_p1.y};

            for (int i {t_p1.y}; i < t_p2.y; i++)
            {
                int bufferX = slopeY * i + cY;
                draw(bufferX, i, t_Char, t_Attribute);
            }
        }


    }

    void consoleWindow::renderQuad(Syth::coord vertex1,Syth::coord vertex2, Syth::coord vertex3, Syth::coord vertex4, short t_Char, short t_Attribute)
    {
        drawLine(vertex1, vertex2, t_Char, t_Attribute);
        drawLine(vertex1, vertex3, t_Char, t_Attribute);
        drawLine(vertex1, vertex4, t_Char, t_Attribute);
        drawLine(vertex2, vertex3, t_Char, t_Attribute);
        drawLine(vertex2, vertex4, t_Char, t_Attribute);
        drawLine(vertex3, vertex4, t_Char, t_Attribute);

    }

    void consoleWindow::clear()
    {
        memset(m_ScreenBuf, 0, sizeof(CHAR_INFO)*m_ScreenHeight*m_ScreenWidth); 
    }

    void consoleWindow::update()
    {
        short tempW = m_ScreenWidth;
        short tempH = m_ScreenHeight;
        WriteConsoleOutput(m_hConsole,m_ScreenBuf, {tempW, tempH}, {0,0}, &m_RectWindow);
    }


    consoleWindow::~consoleWindow()
    {
        delete [] m_ScreenBuf;
    }
}
```

SythConsole.h source code:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef UNICODE
    #error Please enable unicode for compiler!
#endif

#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include "SythColour.h"
#include "SythKeyMap.h"
#include "SythUtilities.h"


namespace Syth
{

    class consoleWindow
    {
        protected:
            int m_ScreenWidth;
            int m_ScreenHeight;
            int m_MouseX;
            int m_MouseY;
            std::wstring m_WinName;

            CHAR_INFO *m_ScreenBuf;
            SMALL_RECT m_RectWindow;

            bool m_CursorVis;

            HANDLE m_hConsole;
            HANDLE m_hConsoleIn;
            HANDLE m_hConsoleOrgi;
            

        protected:

            int MakeError(const wchar_t *msg);
            void handleMouseEvent(INPUT_RECORD &t_Record);

        public:

            consoleWindow();
            ~consoleWindow();

        public:

            int ConstructConsole(int width, int height, int fontW, int fontH, std::wstring t_winName, bool t_CursorVis);

            int getWidth() const;
            int getHeight() const;
            int getMouseX() const;
            int getMouseY() const;
            void updateInputEvents();

            void clip(int &t_X, int &t_Y);
            void draw (int t_X, int t_Y, short t_Char, short t_Attribute);
            void fill(coord t_Start, coord t_End, short t_Char, short t_Attribute);
            void drawString(int t_X, int t_Y, std::wstring t_String, short t_Attribute);
            void drawLine(coord t_p1, coord t_p2, short t_Char, short t_Attribute);
            void renderQuad(coord vertex1,coord vertex2, coord vertex3, coord vertex4, short t_Char, short t_Attribute);
            void drawTriangle(coord vertex1, coord vertex2, coord vertex3, short t_Char, short t_Attribute);
            void clear();
            void update();
    };

}
```

Comment: The UNICODE symbol is one you should define in your build system, so `g++ -DUNICODE ...`. Once you graduate to a Makefile or CMake, you can add custom definitions at the top level.

Comment: From your post, this is the time to graduate to a Makefile that can compile your project in one shot.

Comment: @Botje Yeah, I will start looking into Makefiles and CMake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pre processor macros are local to each translation unit. There's no way to make a macro definition in main.cpp to be seen in SythConsole.cpp.

If SythConsole.h requires UNICODE to be defined, then you must define that macro in all translation units that include the header.

If a macro needs to be defined in all translation units, then you shouldn't define it in the source, but rather define it when invoking the compiler.

> How can I link the source file with the main file?

Source files aren't linked. Linking is done with object files that are the result of compiling translation units. The compiler command that you use links the compiled program correctly.

But linking is irrelevant to the problem involving macros. Pre processor macros are handled by the pre processor and pre processing happens before compilation (or it can be seen as a sub-step of compilation) while linking happens after compilation.